# Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, iis-6, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've got the dreaded **PageRequestManagerServerErrorException** which occurs on the production server *only*, and is totally fine locally when debugging via visual studio.  The exact message is:

> Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:
>   Test@welpldan.co.uk welpldan
>   m.edmondson@welpldan.co.uk
>   webapplicationerrors@welpldan.co.uk
>       Source File: http://test.hello.co.uk/ScriptResource.axd?d=4HQtQGTwnsRG4PutUsFynbl8XMYYj4QIRFtIW4RZQ8wtsaB2YQ6RjjF5hTDuTExy3ehDqjnjTRabkh87NYMlZ8BJGafLkm0_nDMwcT6kiXl1ZfBXP7VMLM1bW3gMjahEyOwG0zVhwS-eLr3pDl7HSxSeSzj5WC_iB-E_yJK3HKQVRCZl0&t=ffffffffca02224d
>       Line: 1111

which is reported by Internet Explorer in a javascript debug window.

I've read the threads that mention refraining from using `response.Write()` and filters but we don't have anything in the project that should modify the output like that, and it works locally no problems.

Using fiddler I captured the servers' response:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> 87|error|500|Test@welpldan.co.uk
>   Welplan m.edmondson@welpldan.co.uk
>   webapplicationerrors@welpldan.co.uk|

Any ideas?

Comment: if the form you are posting to an aspx page via a partial postback has some html tag elements this will cause the asp.net request validation to fire-up. The final result is somewhat same. PS: this is just another way to re-create a similar problem